# $ax^2 -bx +c =0$ where $a,b,c$ are natural nos. and it has roots lying in the interval $(1,2)$...

Tags: quadratics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $p(x)$ be $ax^2 -bx +c =0$ where $a,b,c$ are natural nos. and it has roots lying in the interval $(1,2)$, then find the minimum value of $a,b,c$ individually.

I started writing $p(x)$ as $a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ and made these equations in both the forms:

$\Delta > 0$

$-b/2a$ lies between $1,2$

and  $p(1),p(2) >0$

but anyways I cant get the minimum value of $a,b,c$ specifically.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that it should be $ax^2 + bx + c$ and not $ax^2 - bx + c$? If you restrict the coefficients to be in the natural numbers, then no such quadratic has both roots positive (and therefore they can't lie in the desired interval).

Comment: Yaa.. I feel the same, but it is given +ve in the book..

Comment: Maybe a printing mistake in the book..

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply out your polynomial to get $ax^2-a(\alpha+\beta)x+a\alpha\beta$ we can see that $a$ can be $1$.  It cannot be $0$ if we take "roots" to indicate there are two of them.  If $a,\alpha,$ and $\beta$ are all positive, $b \lt 0$ and there is no solution to the problem as stated.  If the polynomial is $ax^2-bx+c$ we have $b=a(\alpha+\beta)$ with $\alpha,\beta \gt 1$, so the minimum value of $b$ is $2$.  Similarly, $c=a\alpha \beta$ must be at least $2$.  These conditions are not independent.  In fact $x^2-2x+2=0$ has no real roots at all.  We need to increase $b$ to get the parabola to hit the axis at all.  I don't find any polynomial that fits the requirement with roots at $1,2$ disallowed by the fact that the interval is open.  If you close the interval, $x^2-3x+2=0$ has roots at $1,2$

Answer (score 0):

Let $r,s$ be the roots. $2<-\dfrac{b}{a} = r+s <4$ and so $-4a<b<-2a$. But this means $b$ is negative and not a natural number.